# Reduce the tag wiki upvote requirement for stackexchange betas

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, tag-wiki

I don't know if this has been done already, but it would make sense to reduce the amount of upvotes required to make tag wikis during private and public betas. Since there is still no public accountability (= history), I guess something like 15 upvotes wouldn't be terrible.

Yes, I've read the faq this time, I promise.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the top-20 answerers for a tag and have enough rep, you don't need 100 upvotes.